# How do I fill form elements via onblur events?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a user form in which I have to fill all information related to a user. I have only the email address, and I'd like all other fields to be filled when I enter the email address by using the onblur event. So I have to create a module that is called after I have filled email on the form. Via the module I will fetch all other field data.

Comment: Are the users that are you inserting their email addresses already registered at the site? Do you mean that you need to pull their information form their profile fields stored already in the database?

Comment: yes,i got my point.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to AJAXify the form. Take a look at [this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056) for more info on Drupal AJAX forms. To actually look up the user info you can just use the `user_load_by_mail()` function ([more info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7)).